# Translating MySQL XML output fieldnames to usable tag names

Tags: mysql, xml, xslt, mariadb

I am trying to get the data from a MariaDB database into a 3rd party program running on a machine that does not have access to the DB server, so I need to use flat text files.

CSV is not an option, as the program reading the data does not play well with escapes and quotations.

So I am stuck with XML for now. Luckily MySQL, or MariaDB, allow for the `--xml` parameter in both `mysql` and `mysqldump` command line tool.

However, all columns have the name 'field' with an attribute name=*"column_name"*:

```
shell> mysql --xml -uroot -e "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version%'"
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<resultset statement="SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version%'" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<row>
<field name="Variable_name">version</field>
<field name="Value">5.0.40-debug</field>
</row>

<row>
<field name="Variable_name">version_comment</field>
<field name="Value">Source distribution</field>
</row>
```

For the program reading this data to be able to understand it, I need it to be in the following format:

```
<row>
<Variable_name>version</Variable_name>
<Value>5.0.40-debug</Value>
</row>

<row>
<Variable_name>version_comment</Variable_name>
<Value>Source distribution</Value>
</row>
```

I have written a little XSLT stylesheet to convert this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="field[@name]">
  <xsl:element name="{@name}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which works, but is very slow for larger datasets (100k records, 2M lines XML) using Xalan C++ from the command line. It can take up to 15-30 minutes.

Are there better ways to accomplish this? It is really too bad we can't tell MySQL / MariaDB to output XML using normal tag names instead of these generic ones and having to translate it after the export.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the program reading the data?

Comment: I need to import some data into Qlikview, which is somewhat limited in XML / CSV formats. Prefered method of direct connection through ODBC is not an option, sadly.

Comment: Add `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` to XSLT after the `<xsl:output ...>` to speed up processing. Another solution is use a general-purpose language (Java, PHP, Python) that connects to db, iterates through rows, creating a dom XML file.

Comment: Well, initially I had the XML generated through Rails instead of directly through the database, but this also made the process unacceptable slow. So any intermediary programming languages are probably not really useful.

Comment: If it can handle _some_ form of CSV, use Perl/MySQL/PHP/etc to convert the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following resource to handle the xml dump from MySQL.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_query_document.htm

I can loop thru the field name tags to get the name/value pair.